# Miso Marinade Did Not Char

Tags: fish, broiling

I followed [this](https://www.seriouseats.com/easy-broiled-miso-marinated-black-cod) miso recipe and cooked it on a foil lined sheet pan directly under the broiler.

Somehow, I only succeeded in burning the excess marinade on the foil, whereas all the marinade coating the fish retained its light brown miso color.

Any ideas as to what could have prevented it from browning properly?

Comment: Welcome to SA!  You appear to have forgotten to link to the recipe ... try again?

Comment: Sort about that! Edited.

Comment: Some of the comments on that recipe note that if they put the pan too close to the broiler, the marinade burned. How far away from the heating element was the fish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made that recipe before.  Lopez-Alt's assertions to the contrary, getting a good browning on the miso sauce is actually highly dependent on having a good, pre-heated broiler and having the fish exactly the right distance away.  The first time I made it, I had the same result as you; the fish was fully cooked but the sauce hadn't browned.

Here's things you can do to make browning better with this, but you'll have to tinker around and try various ones to get the combination that works in your oven:

- Precook the marinade, reducing it by 1/3 and making it thicker
- Add 2 Tbs more sugar do the marinade
- Pre-heat your broiler making sure that it's very hot before you put the fish in
- Test distances of 4cm to 10cm from the broiling element/flame
- Make sure the sauce isn't thicker than 3mm on top of the fish
- Finish it with a blowtorch

Good luck with this.  At least it tastes delicious regardless of whether it's browned or not.

Comment: +1 for a hands-on answer! And I never considered that you may have more than 3 mm of marinade built onto the fish, that would indeed require extremely long times for charring.

Comment: Yeah, that was my main mistake the first time; I had extra marinate so I piled it on.  Was never gonna brown.

Comment: Thank you for the incredible answer. Can’t wait to try again.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound overly easy, but it is, in fact, the solution - things char all by themselves under a broiler. All you have to do is to leave it there until it chars. It is practically certain that it will happen.